# How to get my log file from GitHub Actions?

Tags: java, github, gradle, github-actions

I decided to try GitHub Actions. And it failed =)

I have a little understanding on what is how the whole process works, but need some help.

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
DragAndDrop > dragAndDropValidation() FAILED
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException at DragAndDrop.java:26

1 test completed, 1 failed

> Task :test FAILED
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/runner/work/theinternetTests/theinternetTests/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
```

How to I see what is in that **report file**?

The tests don't fail on my local machine, so I can't replicate it there.

Comment: Add a conditional step to your action and print the log file if the build (previous step) failed. You could use something like `cat <path_to_log_file>` to print your log file.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the gradle.build file to increase the log level.

```
test {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
    }
}
```